# Is there a configuration setting in Play Framework to enable cache-control header in the response sent to the client

Tags: scala, playframework

I need to enable Cache-Control in the response with the value "no-cache" in all the HTTP responses from my controllers. I am using Play 2.5.x (Scala 2.11.11). Play documentation does not have any mention. Searching on the web shows a suggestion to add `http.cacheControl=0` to enable this heading in configuration file. I tried this but it does not work (neither in dev nor in prod mode).
Any suggestions ?

Comment: As I know `http.cacheControl` is not supported by play 2.x. I think you can implement filter as mentioned here https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaHttpFilters to add cache control header to all responses.

Comment: I was planning to use the filter approach if there is no config param. Seems that's the only way. Will use filter. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well the `cache-control` will be in the header of your responses, and you need to write a filter for it, as shown in ['A simple logging filter'](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaHttpFilters#A-simple-logging-filter). So you could change the example to contain the information about the `cache control` as following:

```
result.withHeaders("Cache-Control" -> "no-cache")
```

or perhaps give the value `0` to the maximum age:

```
result.withHeaders("Cache-Control" -> "max-age=0")
```

Comment: Added the header in my existing Logging filter code. Works fine. Thanks.

Comment: @NKM great! Glad I could help.